# Can anyone access protected (with .htaccess) json files in the host?

Tags: json, apache, .htaccess

I have important `config.json` file, contains important data (like database username, password, etc...) and I'm protecting it using htaccess.

Can anyone access this file using any method (like hacking or anything like that)?

Full htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    RewriteEngine On
    # RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    Options -Indexes
    # protect files
    <FilesMatch "\.(sql|data|conf|dat|json|inf|info)$">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

** Related Info: The server I'm using is apache with PHP code. Also my files is in a shared hosting company. **

Comment: You should not at all keep such sensitive data in the file system part which is published via the http server. Place it outside and you have a robust solution.

Comment: And to answer your question in a simple manner: certainly it might be possible to access that file using adequate methods (you named "hacking"). It certainly is impossible to guarantee that anyone won't somehow be able to access such file if your system is compromised.

Comment: I would say: put that .json file out of the webroot and encrypt sensitive information in the .json file